# Access keeps losing connection to Sharepoint list

Tags: database-connection, microsoft-access

I'm setting up an Access 2010 database to have a table that is linked to a Sharepoint list, and I'm experiencing connectivity problems.

Whenever I edit a record in the linked table, and then press down to complete the edit, Access always loses connectivity to Sharepoint, and then when I reconnect, I get a warning saying that there are conflicts between my changes and the ones that I made several minutes ago, even for fields that I didn't change on this edit.

In addition, Access seems to intermittently disconnect from Sharepoint at random, requiring me to keep a constant eye on the bottom-right corner of the screen so I can restore the connection and synchronize.

This is not happening for all the sites on the Sharepoint server; I was able to connect and stay connected to a sandbox site that I created.  The list I'm trying to connect to has 41 fields; I'm wondering if the size might be an issue for connection stability.

Comment: Are you connecting to a SP 2010 site?

Comment: @RyanErickson, no, it's SP 2007.

Comment: It may be an issue with the office and sharepoint versions not matching up. Are you able to try this with Access 2007?

Comment: @RyanErickson: no, all the machines here are Access 2010.  I don't think it's a version mismatch issue, because the sandbox site that I successfully connected to is also on a SP2007 server in the same intranet.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing similar issues with a db that also has a table with a very large number of fields. Thanks
Morgan

Comment: I ended up just connecting to the site via Sharepoint Web Services (in C# .NET and VBA), instead of using Access.  It needs a lot more coding, especially for building CAML queries and parsing the XML results, but it's more reliable.

Comment: Same issue here with Sharepoint 2013 list and Access 2013. "All tables are disconnected." Then it wants to synchronize my changes with my own changes, which makes no sense.